# Misunderstanding the definition of kernel in digraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs, orientation

By [Borodin–Kostochka–Woodall '97](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(98)00091-0) paper, the first paragraph says that directed odd cycles do not have kernels. But, I don't get this. Like, consider any $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ set of independent vertices in an odd cycle, and we orient every other vertex in the remaining set of vertices to one of the vertices in the independent set. So, don't we get a kernel? What exactly is missing here? Any light on this regard? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I think you are not allowed to pick the orientation yourself, i.e. the edges are all oriented clockwise or they are all oriented counterclockwise.

Comment: @1001 but that is not mentioned in the paper, right. In fact, in any paper defining a kernel, they only say that a kernel is an independent dominating set in a digraph

Comment: @vidyarthi By definition, a directed graph has a given orientation. And a **directed cycle** is a cycle which is oriented so that each vertex has one edge coming in and one edge going out.

Comment: @bof ok, thanks